# Is there a centralized place for finding all the aggregated traffic stats at the Vnet level or NSG level in Azure via APIs?

Tags: azure

I was trying to get Aggregated traffic flow Stats at a Vnet level in my Azure Subscription. AWS has Cloudwatch log groups to which I can redirect the all the VPC flowlogs. I can do one API query to get the flow logs for the entire VPC. I am trying to achieve the same thing on Azure.In Azure, only way seems to be querying each NIC and getting the traffic Stats.Can somebody suggest any alternative to get the Aggregated Stats in Azure?

I explored Azure Monitor Metrics, but it seems to be at each resource level(per NIC).I have explored Azure Network watcher at the NSG level.
But again, it is per MAC per one hour.I explored traffic analytics on the Network Watcher, but I am having trouble in finding the APIs to read the Stats from Traffic Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is anything like that. All the metrics are bound to NICs\NSG. not to vnet.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.Even at the NSG level flow logs, it is still per NIC.Looking for something more aggregated rather than per Mac.